# Arabic and nonlatin characters work offline but show question marks

Tags: php, mysql, arabic-support

I have a multi language website, it worked fine offline and online, suddenly after asking the hosting provider to lessen security, arabic and nonlatin characters show?, funny thing is that data retrieved from mysql database works normal, which usually is supposed to be the hard part, but anything I type in arabic or non latin, even if I place them in php variables and make echo they cannot be displayed

Comment: I would guess you might need to explicitly set a character set for you HTML page.

Comment: All is set
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> is placed also:
<?php
mb_internal_encoding( "UTF-8");
?>

Comment: Did you try setting the charset as http header too? `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: yes I did, same result: this is the website: 
http://www.worlddriversassociation.com/Arabic/Car-Vehicle-License
and what comes from mysql reads ok, this faq reads from mysql ok: http://www.worlddriversassociation.com/testimonials some of the testimonials are arabic from mysql and they read ok